# Laplace transform of a time varying positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, laplace-transform, positive-semidefinite

Consider a real, symmetric matrix $M(t)$ with time-varying elements. Each of the elements are zero for $t<0$ and positive for $t\geq 0$. Assume that $M(t)\succeq 0 \;\forall t\geq 0$ (i.e., it is positive semidefinite).

Is the following matrix obtained by taking Laplace transform of $M(t)$ also positive semidefinite?
$$
\int_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{-s t} M(t) dt.
$$
Here $s$ is a complex number.

Comment: positive semidefinite for all values of $s$? Including zero? If positive definite the integral would blow up for real negative $s$?

Comment: No, only for those values of $s$ for which the Laplace transform makes sense.